# Holomorphic function such that $f(1/n)=1/n^2$, not $z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $f(1/n)=1/n^2$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and where $f$ is not the function $z^2$.

I've tried thinking of many different options for this problem, but I can't seem to come up with one that works.

Would a piecewise function be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent problem of finding a holomorphic function on $\Bbb C^*$ such that $g(1/n)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N\setminus \{0\}$ is perhaps more evocative, because there is $\sin \frac{\pi}{ x}$. And then $f(z)=z^2+g(z)$ works.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks! :)